# Taking photos without photons?

Tags: photons, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, schroedingers-cat

I was looking up some science news and I came across this!

**Blind quantum camera snaps photos of Schrödinger’s cat**
http://www.sciencenews.org/article/blind-quantum-camera-snaps-photos-schr%C3%B6dinger%E2%80%99s-cat

http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature13586

Can somebody please explain how is this possible?

Comment: I have a feeling, that the interpretation of these authors, about what their experiment does, is wrong. I think they are hoping to achieve a clear separation of photons into different light paths (i.e. labeling) by frequency separation, which seems to remove the impossibility to distinguish between photons that have taken one light path vs. the other in a conventional interference experiment. The problem is, that the experiment makes the state of the atoms in their non-linear dividers part of their experiment, which is neglected in the analysis in the abstract, and would be an error.

Comment: Looks like it's all about entangled pairs.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft So is this possible or not? Have the authors misinterpreted it?

Comment: @rahulgarg12342 yes

Comment: it's not a direct live, informations are built when they compute correlations. We live an historical epoch, historians will write a lot on it , probably after a fundamental change in the grant system.

Comment: I remember _Science News_.  I Haven't seen much reason to read it since Ivars Peterson left.

Comment: On this site we normally require questions to include all information needed so that a reader with expert physics knowledge can answer the question. Here the question asks "how is this possible" but "this" is not defined anywhere. These sorts of questions are discouraged because 1) From the post we have no idea what you're asking 2) We have to read an entire journal article to find out what you *might* be asking, 3) the links can rot, and 4) if you take the time to formulate a specific question you're *way* more likely to figure it out on your own.

Comment: It is confusing because they say superposition when they mean entanglement. The yellow beam containing the information about the cutout got it from an entangled red beam which made contact with the cutout.  In fact, National Geographic has a much better article: http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/08/140827-quantum-imaging-cats-undetected-photon-science/